# combine variable and cell address in a formula

Tags: vba

I have following piece of code:

```
Dim displacement As Double
    init_displacement = Range("C3").Value

Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("E2:E" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2] - [" & init_displacement & "]"
```

I can't find in the manual or online whats the correct expression to substract from formula when combined with cell addresses. Anybody please?

UPDATE:

I ended up using

```
poc_posuv = (CLng(-(Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value)))
```

However this takes the C2 value of 22,651 (notice the decimal comma) and rounds it up to 23. Anybody has an idea why the CLng function does that? It seems pretty <strike>stupid</strike> unreasonable to assign the Long data type and still round it up...

Comment: Please edit your post to replace the [tag:variables] tag with the tag for the programming language you are using (I assume that it's VBA?).

Comment: sry, always forget ;)

Comment: So I should use CDbl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
"=RC[-2] - " & init_displacement
```

i.e. no square brackets.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, unfortunatelly that results in 1004 error

Comment: This will work. I think your problem is that cell C3 is blank.so init_displacement is empty.

Comment: Unfortunatelly... it is not blank. I use the Watch to check the stored value of init_displacement and the value is correct

still getting the 1004 :-/

Comment: I tried it; it works for me. If it doesn't work for you, then please give us enough info to reproduce the error, else it's really difficult to help. For example what's the value of `init_displacement` and of `lastrow`?

Comment: Problem is the definition of varible... if I replace the number with an integer it works just fine. Ok Im lost here, Long should be correct

Comment: Is the decimal point character (as ".") set or varies with region? Or is it set? because my excel uses "," as a decimal point - maybe VBA can't handle that...

Comment: Good guess, but I just tried with both `,` and `.` as decimal separators (File > Options > Advanced > Editing options) and both work just fine. Please just show us the value of `init_displacement` and of `lastrow`. Incidentally, `init_displacement` is not declared using `Dim`...

Comment: init_displacement is 22,561. I tested again and it really seems that its the decimal separator issue. I also tried the CLng function but it rounds up the number

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the RC for the second Cell. 
Replace

"=RC[-2] - [" & init_displacement & "]"

with

"=RC[-2] - RC[" & init_displacement & "]"

Comment: Hmm I should rephrase - the result Im loooing for is

=RC[-2]-22.631

That should be the formula filled in the cells (init_displacement in my current worksheet is 22.631)

Comment: In that case remove the second set of square brackets and it should work fine. That is  "=RC[-2] - " & init_displacement